# How to deploy .net framework console app to one exe file without run time

Tags: c#, visual-studio, deployment, .net-framework-version

I want to deploy the .net framework console app and I want it to be in one .exe file but not include run time.
I have tried a similar thing with the .net 5 projects using this command:

```
dotnet publish -r win-x64 /p:PublishSingleFile=true /p:IncludeNativeLibrariesForSelfExtract=true --output "the path"
```

I have looked around the Web but could not find any working source
I am using .net framework 4.6

Comment: I think you have to create an installation package, because your console might have other files or DLLs from other packages that can't be included into one EXE file.  Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/deployment/installer-projects-net-core?view=vs-2022